# How to display or use variables in Discord.RichEmbed()

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I am not able to include variables within a richembed on my Discord bot.

I'm an absolute noob to Javascript and Discord bots. I have tried putting the code within the richembed (which doesn't work at all..) and placing the embeds at the bottom of the javascript file, amongst other things.

```
  // Get information on models
  if (msg.content.startsWith('!info')) {
    // Get first (category) argument and 2nd (model name) category
    const args = msg.content.slice('!info'.length).split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    // Set arguments as variables
    const cat = args[0]
    const model = args[1]
    // Check if the model exists in the category
    if (fs.existsSync(dirPath + cat + "/" + model)) {
      const modelInfo = fs.readFileSync(dirPath + cat + "/" +model, "utf8");
      msg.channel.send(embedModelInfo);
    } else {
      // If it doesn't, display an error
      msg.channel.send('ERROR: ' + cat + ' is not a valid category and/or model. Run "!listcat" for a list of categories and to list models within said categories.');
    }
    msg.channel.send('_ _');
    msg.channel.send('READY.');
  }
```

```
var embedModelInfo = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor('777575')
  .setTitle('Model Information')
  .setAuthor('Printbot', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparrdrem/printbot/master/_previmg.png')
  .setThumbnail('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparrdrem/printbot/master/_previmg.png')
  .addField(modelInfo, '_ _')
  .addField('_ _', '_ _')
  .addField('READY.', '_ _')
```

I'd expect the embedded page to print the modelInfo variable, however Node.JS crashes saying "modelInfo is not defined", even though it is defined as shown above.

Comment: ModelInfo is defined within the scope of your `If` statement. It not reachable when you call it in `addField`, it's out of scope at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The embedModelInfo definition needs to go in between the modelInfo definition and the `message.channel.send(embedModelInfo)`

```
if (fs.existsSync(dirPath + cat + "/" + model)) {
  const modelInfo = fs.readFileSync(dirPath + cat + "/" +model, "utf8");
  var embedModelInfo = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor('777575')
    .setTitle('Model Information')
    .setAuthor('Printbot', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparrdrem/printbot/master/_previmg.png')
   .setThumbnail('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparrdrem/printbot/master/_previmg.png')
    .addField(modelInfo, '_ _')
    .addField('_ _', '_ _')
    .addField('READY.', '_ _');
  msg.channel.send(embedModelInfo);
}
```